# Fetch Random data from a table in access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in access with a field name "ID".
I wanna fetch 3 random data from this table.
How Should i do that?

Comment: I don't get why there's three minuses and a close on it... +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[one minute google search](http://www.carlj.ca/2007/12/16/selecting-random-records-with-sql/)

```
SELECT TOP 3 ID
FROM Table
ORDER BY Rnd(Field1)
```

Comment: Did you select `TOP 3` randomly?

Comment: @Dennis AFAIK, I think it orders the table first, then selects the top 3. The author on the referenced site claims to have tested, so it probably works.

Comment: I somehow missed the last line. `TOP 3` just reminded me immediately of [xkcd: Random Number](http://xkcd.com/221/).

Comment: @Dennis Well, technically... :p